# VLC creating all the default folders in home directory again

Tags: 16.04, vlc

I have changed the default folder location for the most of home directory folders but I noticed that after installing vlc those folders are again got created in the home directory with an additional folder called **snap**. Every time I delete these folders they get created again on re-opening VLC media player.

What should I do to avoid this?

[image]